# How to paste programmatically on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, paste, osx-mavericks, nspasteboard

I have access to the general `NSPasteboard`. I wrote to the pasteboard my `NSData`.

```
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];

[pboard clearContents];
[pboard setData:newContent forType:type];
```

Now I want to paste **programmatically**.
The *text cursor* is blinking on the correct position **in another app**.
Hitting ⌘ + V works.

Somebody know how?
Maybe how to paste with calling the shortcut programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to perform the paste action in your own app, then you can use the Responder Chain to send the `paste:` action to the first responder:

```
[NSApp sendAction:@selector(paste:) to:nil from:self];
```

The documentation says what happens when you pass `nil` as the `to:` parameter:

> If aTarget is nil, sharedApplication looks for an object that can respond to the message—that is, an object that implements a method matching anAction. It begins with the first responder of the key window.

However, if you want to perform the paste action in *another* app, there's no real good way to do that.  The best you can hope for is to perform a "pretend" <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> operation and hope that that means "paste" in the target app...

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
CGEventRef pasteCommandDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, kVK_ANSI_V, YES);
CGEventSetFlags(pasteCommandDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);

CGEventRef pasteCommandUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, kVK_ANSI_V, NO);

CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, pasteCommandDown);
CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, pasteCommandUp);

CFRelease(pasteCommandUp);
CFRelease(pasteCommandDown);
CFRelease(source);
```

As mentioned in another comment, this is kind of a gross way to do it.  It's somewhat unsafe (you don't always know what <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> means) and is pretty hackish.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. In `Carbon.h` are the key codes, so now I can exchange *kVK_ANSI_...* and *kCGEventFlagMask...* so every key press is possible.

Comment: @Dave Delong i tried above lines but paste event not triggering in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a non-custom view:

when a view conforms to copy & paste, it has a copy and a paste method. GIVEN that the keyboard cmd+v works, it does indeed have paste: as a method

`call [target paste:nil];`

Comment: the idea is that the view knows how to handle the data.. e.g. a textview would get the pasteboard's textual content and append it to its attributed string

Comment: The text cursor is in another app. So I don't know how to get the target. Updated the question.

Comment: you emulate the key press only (BUT that is WAY hackish)